# How to store a cfdictionaryref into an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, exc-bad-access, objective-c++

I am trying to store the parameters of an audiounit into an NSDictionary using the following method.

```
OSStatus AudioEngineModel::getParameterStateOfEffect(NSInteger nEffectID, CFDictionaryRef * pcfDictRef_ParameterData, UInt32* pun32DataSize)
{
    Boolean outWritable;
    OSStatus err= AudioUnitGetPropertyInfo(m_aEffectNodes[nEffectID].audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_ClassInfo, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &*pun32DataSize, &outWritable);
    if(err != noErr)
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR AudioEngineModel::getParameterStateOfEffect:: AudioUnitGetPropertyInfo\n");
        return err;
    }

    *pcfDictRef_ParameterData= (CFDictionaryRef)malloc(*pun32DataSize);

    err= AudioUnitGetProperty (m_aEffectNodes[nEffectID].audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_ClassInfo, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, (void*)*pcfDictRef_ParameterData, &*pun32DataSize);
    if(err != noErr)
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR AudioEngineModel::getParameterStateOfEffect:: AudioUnitGetProperty\n");
        return err;
    }    


    m_cfDictRef_ParameterData= *pcfDictRef_ParameterData; 
    m_pdParameterData= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)m_cfDictRef_ParameterData];

    return noErr;                               
}
```

Everything works great until the `NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:` call, where I consistently get exc_bad_access.

I call this method like so.

```
CFDictionaryRef cfDictRef_ParameterData;
UInt32 un32DataSize;    
OSStatus err= [[[NSApp delegate] getMainController] getParameterStateOfEffect:m_nEffectTypeID parameterData:&cfDictRef_ParameterData dataSize:&un32DataSize];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in these lines:

```
*pcfDictRef_ParameterData= (CFDictionaryRef)malloc(*pun32DataSize);

err= AudioUnitGetProperty (m_aEffectNodes[nEffectID].audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_ClassInfo, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, (void*)*pcfDictRef_ParameterData, &*pun32DataSize);
```

The malloc is unnecessary. AudioUnitGetProperty will return a CFDictionaryRef for kAudioUnitProperty_ClassInfo. Since pcfDictRef_ParameterData is already a CFDictionaryRef*, you don't need to allocate anything.

You do need to pass the pointer to the CFDictionaryRef (not dereferenced) to AudioUnitGetProperty. So the second line should be:

```
err= AudioUnitGetProperty (m_aEffectNodes[nEffectID].audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_ClassInfo, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, (void*)pcfDictRef_ParameterData, pun32DataSize);
```

instead.

Comment: But how do I create the CFDictionaryRef with CFDictionaryCreate if I can't access my *pcfDictRef_ParameterData's keys/values. I've tried but calling those methods gives me another exc_bad_acess.

Comment: I also tried putting the data of *pcfDictRef_ParameterData into a NSData object with this: m_pParameterData= [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void*)*pcfDictRef_ParameterData length:*pun32DataSize]; It lets me store the data in here, but when I call bytes or getBytes: length: I get another exc_bad_access. Any Ideas?

Comment: Didn't realize the call returned a CFDictionaryRef for that property. So what happens if you get rid of the malloc call and just use: err= AudioUnitGetProperty (m_aEffectNodes[nEffectID].audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_ClassInfo, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, (void*)pcfDictRef_ParameterData, pun32DataSize); Also, why use &*pun32DataSize (instead of just pun32DataSize) in the AudioUnitGetPropertyInfo call?

Comment: I took away the malloc and after AudioUnitGetProperty() I tried to do this m_pdParameterData= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)*pcfDictRef_ParameterData]; and got exc_bad_access again on the NSDictionary call. The &*pun32DataSize was just a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Did you change the AudioUnitGetProperty to use (void*) pcfDictRef_ParameterData, instead of (void*)*pcfDictRef_ParameterData?

Comment: Thank you very much for spending the time to figure this one out.

Comment: No problem. Sorry for missing an important detail (that a CFDictionaryRef is being returned as the value of the property) in the original answer.